# C++ - OpenGL crash on glDrawElements()

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++

So in my program I have a number of textures that I am trying to display. Earlier in my code I generate the VAO for the textures and the ibo (or index buffer) for each texture. But when I run my code it crashes at the `glDrawElements()` call and in nvoglv32.dll. I've read around that a bug in the nvidia driver might be causing it but I doubt it. Something is probably wrong when I generate or bind the VAO or ibo but I have no idea where. Here's the section of code where the error happens:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXTURES; i++){

    glBindVertexArray(VAO_T[i]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[i]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);

    //error here
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));//error right here

}
```

This is the error I get when running in debug:

Unhandled exception at 0x0263FE4A in Comp465.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Heres my code where I generate the VAO, ibo, and textures:

```
glGenVertexArrays(NUM_TEXTURES, VAO_T);
glGenBuffers(NUM_TEXTURES, VBO_T);
glGenBuffers(NUM_TEXTURES, ibo);
glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, texture);

...

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXTURES; i++){

    //Tel GL which VAO we are using
    glBindVertexArray(VAO_T[i]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices[i]), indices[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //initialize a buffer object
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_T[i]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_T[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(point[i]) + sizeof(texCoords), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(point[i]), point[i]);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(point[i]), sizeof(texCoords), texCoords);

    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(textureShader, "vPosition");
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    GLuint vTexCoord = glGetAttribLocation(textureShader, "vTexCoord");
    glVertexAttribPointer(vTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(point[i])));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoord);

    //Get handles for the uniform structures in the texture shader program
    VP = glGetUniformLocation(textureShader, "ViewProjection");

    //Bind the texture that we want to use
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    // set texture parameters
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    //Load texture
    texture[i] = loadRawTexture(texture[i], TEX_FILE_NAME[i], PixelSizes[i][0], PixelSizes[i][1]);
    if (texture[i] != 0) {
        printf("texture loaded \n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error loading texture \n");
}
```

Comment: Use `glGetError` to check if any call failed.

Comment: I guess `BUFFER_OFFSET` macro just casts to `void*`?

Comment: How did you declare `VAO_T` and `texture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement certainly looks wrong:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_T[i]);
```

`glEnableVertexAttribArray()` takes an attribute location as its argument, not a buffer id. You actually use it correctly later:

```
GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(textureShader, "vPosition");
...
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

GLuint vTexCoord = glGetAttribLocation(textureShader, "vTexCoord");
...
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoord);
```

So you should be able to simply delete that extra call with the invalid argument.

Apart from that, I noticed a couple of things that look slightly off, or at least suspicious:

- The following call is meaningless if you use the programmable pipeline, which you are based on what's shown in the rest of the code. It can be deleted.

  ```
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
  ```
- This is probably just a naming issue, but `textureShader` needs to be a *program* object, i.e. the return value of a `glCreateProgram()`, not a shader object.
- While inconclusive without seeing the declaration, I have a bad feeling about this, and a couple other similar calls:

  ```
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices[i]), indices[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ```

  If `indices[i]` is an array, i.e. the declaration looks something like this:

  ```
  indices[NUM_TEXTURES][INDEX_COUNT];
  ```

  then this is ok. But if `indices[i]` is a pointer, or degenerated to a pointer when it was passed as a function argument, `sizeof(indices[i])` will be the size of a pointer. You may want to double check that it gives the actual size of the index array. Same thing for other similar cases.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Commenting out glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_T[i]); made it work!!